# Dataset transformation with array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, transformation

I have 1 function and it must get 1 parameter(first or second team, only number),  output results you can see below the code. In short function must return 1 team(members with books) or 2 team(members with books)

```js
let get = (team) => {
  let books = [
    { id: 1,  name: 'Good Island', authors: [3] },
    { id: 33,  name: 'Big World', authors: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7] },
    { id: 23, name: 'Nice weather', authors: [7, 2, 3] },
    { id: 333,  name: 'People'},
    { id: 1234,  name: 'Animals' authors: [2] },
    { id: 2,  name: 'Sun', authors: [3, 5] },
  ]

  let authors = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Michael' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Sam' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Margo' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Tom' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Rob' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Pablo Escobar' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Unknown' },
  ]

  let teams = [
    { id: 1, name: 'first team', members: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { id: 2, name: 'second team', members: [5, 6, 7] },
  ]

  return `here must be first or second team`
}
console.log(get(1)) \\ `first team(4 members with books)`
console.log(get(2)) \\ `second team(3 members with books)`
```

As a result of transform I have to get:

```
1 Team: 

Michael wrote 'Big world',
 
Sam wrote 'Big world', 'Nice weather', 'Animals',

Margo wrote 'Good island', 'Big world', 'Nice weather', 'Sun',

Tom wrote 0 books

2 Team: 

Rob wrote 'Big world', 'Sun',

Pablo Escobar wrote 'Big world',

Unknown wrote 'Big world', 'Nice weather'
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or put in any research effort?

Comment: Does your data have to be structured that way? To lookup an author's books you have to loop through the whole book array and each book's author array.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ <<< Please read

Answer (score 0):

```js
let get = (team) => {
  let books = [
    { id: 1,  name: 'Good Island', authors: [3] },
    { id: 33,  name: 'Big World', authors: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7] },
    { id: 23, name: 'Nice weather', authors: [7, 2, 3] },
    { id: 333,  name: 'People'},
    { id: 1234,  name: 'Animals', authors: [2] },
    { id: 2,  name: 'Sun', authors: [3, 5] },
  ]

  let authors = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Michael' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Sam' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Margo' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Tom' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Rob' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Pablo Escobar' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Unknown' },
  ]

  let teams = [
    { id: 1, name: 'first team', members: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { id: 2, name: 'second team', members: [5, 6, 7] },
  ]

  text = team + ' Team:\n';
  let members = teams[team-1].members;  //index starts from 0

  let author_books = authors;   //new list for author and books

  for (let member of members) {          //iterating member ids
    author_books[member-1].books = []   //adding key books for ids
    for(let item in books)              //iterating all items of books
      if (books[item].authors)          //checking if author exists
        if(books[item].authors.includes(member))    //checking if list consists of this author
          author_books[member-1].books.push(books[item].name);  //adding book to list
  }

  for (let member of members) {     //comparing members list with that of author_books and storing result
    for (let item of author_books)
      if (item.id == member) {
        temp_text = item.name + " wrote ";
        if (item.books.length != 0) {
          for (book of item.books)
            temp_text += "'" + book + "',";
        } else {
          temp_text += "0 books";
        }
      }
    text += temp_text + '\n';
  }
  // console.log(author_books);
  return text;
}
console.log(get(1)) 
console.log(get(2))
```

Comment: thank you for your attempt but i think there is more easier way to do it ;)